# Cross posting programming questions on Stackoverflow and GameDev.StackExchange

Tags: discussion, etiquette

What are the etiquette involved when cross-posting programming questions on StackOverflow and GameDev.StackExchange? Or is it a case of "don't do it?"

Comment: [This has come up with other site pairs before, and the answer is don't do it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that this would be a good case for don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going for one or the other.

- Wasting peoples' time
  on both ends.
- Likely indicates it doesn't belong here (programming with a slight gamedev issue).

And not just SO - I've seen many questions on here and on Gamedev.net, with post times ~5 minutes of each other.

Comment: +1 for "not just SO".

Comment: The case of an opener asking the same question in 2+ boards is not much different from a user answering 2+ different answers to _the same question_ on 2+ different boards. The latter could be a direct consequence of the first, and both makes no sense. Even more with a largely shared user base and a lot or repetitive questions.

Answer (score 2):

Another vote for SO xor GDSE. As another argument against both, we've had at least one case of a question getting migrated from SO to here after being asked both places, leaving us with a duplicate.

Comment: However, migrated questions can be merged, especially if answers are good on both ends, or deleted entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said and I'm sure you've realized by now, I would not do it either as it wastes people's time.

But I do wish the two sites were merged/combined - because points are divided, and the very issue this question raises.