# Does cross-posting a question make it off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this pretty bad question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98853/error-in-post-a-screen-shot-of-game-scores-with-android-intent-in-libgdx-game). It's basically a code dump so I'm pretty much okay with it being closed.

However, I then saw the close reason used by @Byte56:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's cross posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841735/how-to-capturescreen-shot-of-current-screen-to-share-score-like-temple-run-game – Byte56♦

I know our stance on cross-posting is ["Don't"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/cross-posting-programming-questions-on-stackoverflow-and-gamedev-stackexchange) but I don't feel that cross-posting should make it off-topic (do we then reopen the question if the other copy is closed? Or when it's deleted?).
I'm not looking for this question to be re-opened, I'd have proposed closing it as a code dump.

But in the future, if a good question is cross-posted to other sites what should we do?

Comment: For the record, I'm not starting a witch hunt against @Byte56, he was just the person I saw doing it. I'd say downvoting and leaving a comment about crossposting is the way to go.

Comment: This close was the result of handling a moderator flag. I likely should have picked a different close reason (there are a few that might apply). With cross posted questions, I just try to get them fixed as soon as possible. I hate to see people waste their time on questions that get closed later or merged to a different site because they were cross posted. In this case, the question was pretty old and it wasn't likely I was going to get in contact with the OP anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

Tricky, I've been in the situation where i've been told "post this over here ", so my natural reaction is ... edit > copy > new site > new question > paste ... technically that's cross posting but on the advice of an admin from the source site.

Personally I think the solution here is a move option on questions, this would allow the question to be put in the right place possibly by a high rep user when it happens.

Often the reason is that the user asking the question isn't sure where it belongs (in my case that was also true if I recall).

At the same time, high rep users on the network, certainly on the main SO site seem to take the stance of "if the user didn't RTFM and immediately get it right then jump on them from as high as possible until they do or until they leave".

Closing serves that heavy handed purpose, but I think the site should naturally teach users where things belong if possible.

Feature request: function to administratively vote to move a question / just administratively move it (perhaps with enough rep) which would trigger a decent explanation given to the asker of the question resulting in a better experience overall.

Comment: move option is actually present as a moderator tool.

Comment: Migration is a process that exists as @Ali.S stated, it is however a moderator only process that is quite involved for people on both sites on the network. I don't think that it's a good solution for this as the feature stands.

Comment: My answer was really a suggestion to take that and make it both easier and more readily available to people with lower rep through the existing voting mechanism. High rep mods don't want to deal with this kind of thing all the time and lower rep users would typically pick this up without complaining about it.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, we do close cross-posted questions when we discover them, generally with a custom close reason. We do re-open the question if the remote duplicate is deleted or closed (and we discover *that*).

---

Cross-posting is generally considered a negative impact to the network as a whole, and consequently shouldn't be permitted or encouraged. This is not a universal constant, as the network has no official tools to deal with it (and SE has resisted adding them), and you will find *some* positions on MSE that it's okay if the two sites have vastly different focuses, audiences, and thus viewpoints on the answer.

It's my opinion that closing the question is the right thing to do in this scenario.

- It reinforces, very obviously, the position that cross-posting should usually not happen.
- It helps alleviate some of the negative impact on the network by providing a marker to the singular question (much like duplicates do).
- It doesn't imply that the question is *bad or poorly researched* (as downvoting might).
- But it's still an action with some teeth to it (unlike a simple comment) that encourages the offending user to learn how SE works.